# code crashing when finding the eldest age (Edit)

Tags: c, crash

ok so iffixed it up and me it presentable did some of the suggestions and i get the same error( im using codebloks btw ), the error of it just crashing without giving a reason. I got a second error with this. in the getinfo function after age is entered it prints the statement to get the gender then the statement to get the other persons name without letting me input(it seems to just skip that part

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getinfo (char* nam[],int ag[], char gender[], int count){
 int y;
 for(y = 0; y < count; y++){
 nam[y] = malloc(30);
 printf ("What is the student's name?\t");
 scanf ("%s", &nam[y]);
 printf ("\nWhat is the students age?\t");
 scanf ("%d", &ag[y]);
 printf ("\nwhat is the students gender, M/F:\t");
 scanf ("%c", &gender[y]);
  }
 }

void findeldest (char* nam[],int ag[], char* gender[], int count){
 int largest = 0, y, eldest =0 ;
 for(y = 0; y < count; y++){
    if (ag[y] > eldest){
        largest = ag[y];
        eldest = y;
        }
    }
    printf ("The eldest student is:\t%s", nam[eldest]);
    printf ("\nGender:\t%c", gender[eldest]);
    printf ("\nWith an age of:\t%d", ag[eldest]);

}


int main (){
  int amount, y;
  printf("How many students are you admitting?\t");
  scanf ("%d", &amount);
  if (amount > 50){
  printf("Too many students!");
   }else{
   char *name[50];
   int age[50];
   char gender[50];
   getinfo(name, age, gender, amount);
   findeldest(name, age, gender, amount);
   system("pause");
  }
}
```

Comment: definition of the `getinfo` function?

Comment: Perhaps it crashes in the getinfo function, which is not shown here.

Comment: You are passing the value of `amount` to `getinfo` but I suspect you want to return a value from that function. I can't see that ending well... you probably need to pass `&amount` so you can assign a value to it (whatever your `getinfo` function does).

Comment: @Floris getinfo probably scanfs info into the three pointers, and amount is used as the limit for the loop. He scanfed some value into amount just above

Comment: @GuilhermeBerger ... yes, and probably uses scanf incorrectly, like the code presented here does...

Comment: @GuilhermeBerger you're right.

Comment: @RajayJB Note the amendment to my answer to solve your second (and third) problem.

Answer (score 3):

The code provided isn't compilable and thus we can't diagnose the problem correctly. Please update your post with a compilable testcase that has only the bare essentials required to reproduce your problem.

```
if (ag[y] > eldest){
    largest = ag[y];
    eldest = y;
    } /* <--- Note the inconsistent indentation.
       *      Do you want us to read your code and help you?
       *      If so, please fix your indentation.
       */
```

There's a comparison supposedly on ages, and then an assignment of an index to an age variable? Which does eldest store? Indexes, or ages? Take your pick, and make it consistent. Perhaps it might be a better idea to use more descriptive identifiers, such as "eldest_index" and "eldest_age". This would provide internal documentation that the "eldest_index" is the array index for the oldest person and the "eldest_age" is the age for the oldest person. As it seems largest stores ages, perhaps your code should look more like:

```
if (ag[y] > largest){
    largest = ag[y];
    eldest = y;
}
```

`printf ("\nGender:\t%c", gender[eldest]);` If eldest stores ages, not indexes, then wouldn't this cause your program to crash when `eldest >= 50`? I presume this statement will make more sense when you come up with better identifiers. Furthermore, `gender[eldest]` is a `char *`, where `%c` tells printf to expect an `int` with a character value.

---

*edit*: You wouldn't have encountered your second error if you had read [this scanf manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fscanf.html) before using scanf. In fact, using scanf before reading it's documentation **is** your error; Please stop.

If you place `printf("The character entered for gender has an integer value of %d\n", (unsigned char) gender[y]);` after `scanf ("%c", &gender[y]);`, what value do you get? Is '\n' a valid gender?

... so you've fixed the problem that occurs when the user presses enter between an *integer* read and a *character* read. Great! Without reading the manual, you've got a third problem. Supposing the user presses 'M' or 'F', followed by enter. This would result in either 'M' or 'F' being read from stdin by `scanf ("%c", &gender[y]);`, but the '\n' would remain on stdin. What is the effect of that? When the loop repeats, and you tell scanf to read *up to but not including the next whitespace character* (which is what '%s' indicates), you end up with a blank name! Ooops!

Assuming you expect the user to press *enter* before and after entering gender, I suggest changing `scanf ("%c", &gender[y]);` to:

```
int c;
for (c = getchar(); c >= 0 && c != '\n'; c = getchar());  /* Discard the remainder of the line,
                                                           * so that it doesn't interfere with
                                                           * the gender input.
                                                           */
gender[y] = c;
for (c = getchar(); c >= 0 && c != '\n'; c = getchar());  /* Discard the remainder of the line,
                                                           * so that it doesn't interfere with
                                                           * the next scanf call.
                                                           */
```

... and don't forget to read that scanf manual, *carefully*!

Comment: I'm thinking OP is using the `%c` in the `printf()` call to only print the first character on purpose. Being a gender, just `M` or `F` would be sufficient. Still, it seems a little silly to use a char* for a single character.

Comment: since `eldest` takes the value of `y`, and `y` loops up to 50, I don't think it is possible that `eldest>=50`. Agree with the catch that he should test `ag[y] > largest` - good eye. Agree with the need to provide compileable code. As for the indentation - that's a matter of taste in my mind.

Comment: @shanet: `%c` tells printf to expect an `int` with a character value. A `char *` is not an int with a character value. No conversion occurs, because printf is a function that accepts variable arguments. That's undefined behaviour.

Comment: @floris: I put that there because the function implies a comparison of ages (the function is trying to "get the eldest"), yet the comparison actually assumes that `eldest` stores ages: `if (ag[y] > eldest)`; If you like, I'm trying to guide the OP in the correct direction.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue I wasn't saying it was correct, I was just trying to explain OP's possible thought process and what he/she was trying to achieve (ie, printing only the first character).

Answer (score 1):

You did not post the source code of the getinfo function, so the best we can do here is guess. The first place I would look is in getinfo, when it populates the 'nam' and 'gender' parameters. You are most likely using stack local strings for those. Once the 'getinfo' function returns, those strings no longer exists. The pointers to those locations on the stack still exist however, and whenever findeldest tries to use those pointers in printf, it prints garbage off the stack.

If you supply your 'getinfo' implementation this will be easier. Here is my implementation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void findeldest (char* nam[],int ag[], char* gender[], int count){
  int largest = 0, y, eldest =0 ;
  for(y = 0; y < count; y++){
    if (ag[y] > eldest){
      largest = ag[y];
      eldest = y;
    }
  }
  printf ("The eldest student is:\t%s", nam[eldest]);
  printf ("\nGender:\t%s", gender[eldest]);
  printf ("\nWith an age of:\t%d", ag[eldest]);

}

void getinfo(char* nam[],int ag[], char* gender[], int count)
{
    static const char * const MALE = "male";
    static const char * const FEMALE = "female";

    static const char * const BRIAN = "brian";
    static const char * const SUE = "sue";
    static const char * const DAVE = "dave";
    static const char * const APRIL ="april";



    for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; ++i)
    {
        ag[i] = i;

        switch(i%4)
        {
            case 0:
                nam[i] = BRIAN;
                break;
            case 1:
                nam[i] = SUE;
                break;
            case 2:
                nam[i] = DAVE;
                break;
            case 3:
                nam[i] = APRIL; 
                break;

        }

        switch(i%2)
        {
            case 0:
                gender[i] = MALE;
                break;
            case 1:
                gender[i] = FEMALE;
                break;
        }

    }
    return;
}

int main (){
  int amount, y;
  printf("How many students are you admitting?\t");
  scanf ("%d", &amount);
  if (amount > 50){
    printf("Too many students!");
  } else {
    char *name[50];
    int age[50];
    char *gender[50];
    getinfo(name, age, gender, amount);
    findeldest(name, age, gender, amount);
    system("pause");
  }
}
```

It works fine for me. Notice the correction to the second 'printf' statement in findeldest. You were using %c (single character) when you mean %s (null terminated string of characters).

Also, you are not using C90 compliant code. When posting, you should specify what compiler you are using and what options you need (if any) to make this compile. It appears to be close to valid C99 code. I get some compiler warnings about misuse of const in my 'getinfo' implementation.

Comment: "*When posting, you should specify what compiler you are using and what options you need (if any) to make this compile.*" Clearly a C compiler is being used. That means C11, C99 or C89. C89 isn't the current C standard. At the time when the word *animal*, already widely known as a Latin word, was adopted into English, there was a native word "deer" which had the same meaning. After *animal* came in as a general term, the word *deer* developed it's specialised meaning of "a horned beast". Are you willing to believe that "deer" and "animal" have the same meaning? If so, then so do "C89" and "C".